# Removing First and sometimes Second Word from Column Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to remove the first word and sometimes the first and second word from a column so that I can merge two data frames. For example, in one data frame, the column 'Teams' is in the format Celtics, Nuggets, Lakers. In my second data frame, the column 'Teams' is in the format Boston Celtics, Denver Nuggets, Los Angeles Lakers. I am having trouble because some teams like the Lakers and Pelicans for example have two words before the actual team name 'Lakers' (Los Angeles Lakers, New Orleans Pelicans). I am using Python and Pandas. [Here is an example in List Format of what the column 'Teams' looks like in the data frame I need to manipulate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9iZy.png)

I tried @Nk03 solution [image: Link to code of what I tried is here] and received the output in the screenshot there. I am fairly new to Python so I am confused still as to why the solution did not work.

Comment: No screenshots of code. Please see [ask] and [reprex].

Answer (score 0):

Try this. -

Here, the idea is to extract the part of team name if that part is present in first dataframe -

```
def extract_team(x):
    for item in x.split():
        if item in df1.Teams.values:
            return item
    return x
            
df2.Teams = df2.Teams.apply(lambda x : extract_team(x))
```

Comment: I tried your solution here and re-edited the comment.

Comment: Here in line 132, you're making salary2 = salary1 if both the df's are equal this will not gonna work

Comment: Do one thing load the 1st dataframe with unique single-word names as df1 and 2nd dataframe as df2. Then try this function without changing any stuff.

Comment: when I ran the code without setting salary 2 equal to anything I got an error code saying 'salary2 is not defined' any tips?